# Why doesn't something like select count((select * from producers)) from producers; work?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have defined the following query:

```
select count((select * from producers)) from producers;
```

Assuming a `producers` table with 3 columns (A, B and C) and 2 rows:

```
A B C
-----
0 1 2
3 4 5
```

I'd expect the following output:

```
2
2
```

It doesn't work. While the query itself is basically useless (even if it worked, it wouldn't yield any useful output), I'd like to try to understand why this doesn't run.

```
(select * from producers)
```

This would yield a list of rows with information on all the attributes on the `producers` table.

```
select count((select * from producers)) from producers;
```

This one will for each row on `producers,` show up the number `2` (the number of elements in `producers`).

Why doesn't it work? SQL limitation? Is there anything wrong with the logic I'm following here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a limitation of SQL, as far as I know. Subqueries are not allowed in the `COUNT` expression. Obviously `(select * from producers)` is a subquery, so it's not allowed there.

I think your misunderstanding is that you're thinking that you would call the function like `COUNT(SELECT * FROM producers)` whereas in SQL it's like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM producers`.

Functions like `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, and `COUNT` are *aggregate* functions, meaning that they take a scalar argument but execute once for each row, accumulating results every iteration. So `SELECT MAX(column) FROM table` executes the `MAX` function once for each row in `table`, while you might be thinking that `MAX` executes once and gets passed in every row in `table`.

Contrast this with operators like `IN`, `EXISTS`, `ANY`, and `ALL`, which have a subquery as an argument. They are effectively passed all the results of their subquery every time they are invoked.

Comment: It is not a limitation. It is a function logic. Function `COUNT()` accepts one value.

Comment: But one value of what "type"? It must accept something as an array?

Comment: @devoured elysium: where have you seen `array` in your query? It is just a record set. And `COUNT` expects scalar value.

Comment: "Aggregate functions are also not allowed." -- huh? `COUNT(SUM(field))` - this is a valid expression.

Comment: zerkms: Do you know which DB engines allow `COUNT(SUM(field))` as an expression?

Comment: @Gabe: oracle 10g if it is `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

It should just be

```
Select count(1) from producers;
```

If you are asking about inner selects, then the inner select must be part of the from clause, e.g.

```
Select count(1) from (select * from producers)
```

Both of these do the same but the first is more efficient.

Comment: "Both of these do the same but the first is more efficient." -- it is the same execution plan for both queries. So both has the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` function expects only one value.

This will return what you want:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM producers p1
CROSS JOIN producers p2
  GROUP BY p1.A
```

Comment: Why would you `INNER JOIN ON 1=1` when you could do `CROSS JOIN` or just `FROM producers p1, producers p2`?

Comment: Why does Count() only expect a value? Doesn't Count() take as input a set of rows? My question here is more geared to trying to understand why Count() doesn't allow a query inside, not on how to get a similar output to the query I made.

Comment: "Why does Count() only expect a value? Doesn't Count() take as input a set of rows? " -- because it is. By definition. It accepts one value.

Comment: @Gabe: because 1) i did not know about `cross join`, thanks. 2) i prefer to use obvious `INNER JOIN` instead of `table1, table2` syntax.

Comment: zerkms: I would have to argue that the term `INNER JOIN` is not so obvious when you are do a Cartesian join (as in this case).

Comment: @Gabe: I absolutely agree with you, I did not know about `cross join` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"Why does Count() only expect a value? Doesn't Count() take as input a set of rows? "

Count accepts an expression. If the expression evaluates to null, then it isn't counted. Otherwise it is.

If a table has five rows in it, and one column has three actual values and two null values, then a count of that column would return three.

```
ID  Colour  Size
1   Red     30
2   Blue    <null>
3   <null>  20
4   <null>  <null>
5   Blue    10
```

SELECT COUNT(COLOUR), COUNT(SIZE) would give 3 and 3.

COUNT(*) is special in that it gives the number of rows in the table, irrespective of any nulls.

COUNT can't/won't work with (select * from producers) or even (1,3) as they are not expressions that can be interpreted as null or not null.